# Getting public page's posts (timeline) using FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-timeline

I try to get posts for a public facebook page using FQL:

```
SELECT post_id, created_time, type,like_info.like_count,comment_info.comment_count,message     FROM stream WHERE source_id ='118074121050' and like_info.like_count > 800
```

118074121050 is the ID for public page https://www.facebook.com/cliomakeup
The token i use allows to read stream.

The result of the query just one post while there are many posts with over 800 numbers of likes (according to the page's timeline).

The question is why the fql result does not show me all the posts as they're public?

Comment: Should my answer help, please mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

The [`stream`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream) table also gives posts by users, which doesn't look like being what you need. In order to filter posts from the page owner only, you need to specify the `actor_id` as being the same as the `source_id`:

```
SELECT post_id, created_time, type, like_info.like_count, comment_info.comment_count, message     
  FROM stream 
 WHERE source_id = '118074121050' AND actor_id = '118074121050'
   AND like_info.like_count > 800
```